# keyboard malfunction for hp mini

Tags: keyboard

My keys are not working properly. They (hotkeys, enter, backspace) will only work if I hold down the control key. Keys that only work properly without the aid of control key are <kbd>F3</kbd>, <kbd>T</kbd> and <kbd>Y</kbd>. I tried using an external keyboard but I still have the same issue. Sometimes the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key holds down itself even without pressing it.

Functions like <kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>F9</kbd> will only work if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>. As of now I am using on screen keyboard to type this message. This happened before. After three weeks the keys worked properly. After quite sometime the same problem happened again. I already tried reformatting my unit but the problem still exist.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are on Windows, as you didn't say anything about a Macbook (and to be honest, a Linux user would diagnose this on the spot).

There are some things that affect keyboard usage, mainly, the Windows special accessibility keyboard functions and some program hogging all CPU time (worst case scenario it could be a virus or a keylogger).

First of, check your computer for virus and malware. There are good antivirus suites on the Net, so search for them, for malware I suggest [MalwareBytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org/) although there are others. It this doesn't help, try checking Keyboard and Ease Of Use / Accessibility options on Control Panel.

Last of, try booting your PC on Safe Mode. Maybe it is some conflicting driver.

Comment: I explored my laptop earlier and I found out that the other keys will work if I hold down at least one key that works properly. As of now I am typing this text without the aid of on screen keyboard but I am holding down [ key. Here are some of the keys that work properly : f3, f10, t, y, [ and \. control key works for hot keys only. I reformatted my system with the downloaded os from the net. I noticed that some of the old files are still stored. I was thinking that if this is a virus or malware, what do you suggesst me to do? thank you

Comment: Please read the answer I gave you. Get a good antivirus and a good malware scanner, run them. If after you still have this problem, try the aforementioned steps.

Comment: Linking to [this good answer](http://superuser.com/a/635597/228536) on a similar question.