# How can my keyboard be fix

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp

If I type 'a' it will go to player, and if I type q it will lead for closing programs and ,if I type tab it will restart .How can I fix my keys back to normal? I'm using desktop.

Comment: Please add more detail and specify what problem you have, as it is unclear.

Comment: hm, those don't map to any keyboard combination I am aware of - In addition, you've used both XP and windows 7 tags, and not mentioned if this is a laptop keyboard (could be faulty wiring) or desktop keyboard (could be swapped out to test). There's not really enough information here.

Comment: This is unclear, it really could be a virus, script of AutoHotKey, some really exceptional situation of stuck keys, hardware faults, broken operating system, hacker teasing you, etc...

Answer (score 2):

your onscreen keyboard or your physical keyboard has control key stuck. hope it is the former and you can fix it by open it and unstick it. otherwise you need to fix your keyboard.

Comment: control a dosen't open up the media player for me, nor does control q close things... I'm curious - what specifically makes you think its the control key?

Comment: how can i fix it by opening it and unstick it? :(

Comment: onscreen keyboard is in accessibility section of the start menu, if that is indeed the problem (as opposed to your physical keyboard, which you can test with a different one).

Answer (score 1):

you could have a stuck key(s) (higher possibility), software running that messes with the input, and  having a virus (lower possibility) on the computer.

If it is wireless, then that changes all the possibilites. change the battery, or recharge it, test it on something else.

If a liquid has spilled inside the keyboard, It can take many days to dry it out, a liquid down in there can make a slight connection, or keep a key from moving properly.

If a key item is just stuck sometimes reletlessly pressing it over and over again can get it unstuck.  When you can attribute the problem to a qualifyer key [CTRL] [Win] [ALT] [Shift]  Sometime you can get that key unstuck by pushing it over and over again, until it begins to react.
 Beating on a qualifyer key to try and get it operational, doesnt usually reek havoc on the rest of the system :-)
 When testing keys it can be useful to open up a simple notepad , expand it to full screen, so keypresses (more often) land in something a bit more safe.

Just to be sure , it would not hurt to boot the computer into a "Safe mode" and test it there before assuming it was a hardware only issue. 
If you cannot get into safe mode, it always helps to have Menu or shortcut access to Msconfig.exe. If the keyboard keeps you from getting into Msconfig, (using the mouse) in windows 7 , under `administrative tools` it is the item called `System Configuration`.

Assuming you can get into and use the system with the mouse, there are small utilities that can (sometimes) be used to see what the system thinks is pressed. [Is it possible to show key presses and mouse input visually?](https://superuser.com/questions/594140/is-it-possible-to-show-key-presses-and-mouse-input-visually).